# watchposition and getcurrentposition return inaccurate location in galaxy s22 a53

Tags: javascript, typescript, geolocation

I have a website that is used as an application that uses location, on some devices the location is not accurate especially on Samsung devices like S22 A53, on the other devices it works well.
I emphasize that in other applications such as Google Maps the location is accurate for those devices.
Usually, this is accompanied by an error:
"{code:3,message:Timeout expired}"
But this error also happens to devices that return a good location, I think it's related to the fact that the user clicked refresh location several times.

```
let timeout: number = 10000

export function watchPosition(gotPos: (x: any) => void, gotErr: (x: any) => void) {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    return getCoordinates(gotPos, gotErr)
  }
}

function getCoordinates(gotPos: (x: any) => void, gotErr: (x: any) => void) {
  return navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
    (x: any) => {
      timeout = 10000
      gotPos(x);
    },
    (err: any) => {
      if (Number(err.code) === 3) {
        if(timeout < 100000)
          timeout += 10000
        else
          timeout = 300000
      }
      gotErr(err);
    },
    {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      maximumAge: 0,
      timeout: timeout,
    }
  );
}


let timeout: number = 10000

export function setGPS(gotPos: (x: any) => void, gotErr: (x: any) => void) {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    getCoordinates(gotPos, gotErr)
  }
}

function getCoordinates(gotPos: (x: any) => void, gotErr: (x: any) => void) {
  //Dummy request, which will result in a working next geolocation request.
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function () { }, function () { }, {});

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    (x: any) => {
      timeout = 10000
      gotPos(x);
    },
    (err: any) => {
      if (Number(err.code) === 3) {
        if(timeout < 100000)
          timeout += 10000
        else
          timeout = 30000
      }
      gotErr(err);
    },
    {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      maximumAge: 0,
      timeout: timeout
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what happens if the user has blocked / turned off the location functionality on their devices?  What does your code return then?

Comment: if user bloked location, return  "{\"code\":1,\"message\":\"User denied Geolocation\"}"